# In DataFrame.withColumn, how can I check if the column's value is null as a condition for the second parameter?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I have a DataFrame called df that looks like:

```
+----+----+
|  a1+  a2|
+----+----+
| foo| bar|
| N/A| baz|
|null| etc|
+----+----+
```

I can selectively replace values like so:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("a1", when($"a1" === "N/A", $"a2"))
```

so that df2 looks like:

```
+----+----+
|  a1+  a2|
+----+----+
| foo| bar|
| baz| baz|
|null| etc|
+----+----+
```

but why can't I check if it's null, like:

```
val df3 = df2.withColumn("a1", when($"a1" === null, $"a2"))
```

so that I get:

```
+----+----+
|  a1+  a2|
+----+----+
| foo| bar|
| baz| baz|
| etc| etc|
+----+----+
```

Edit: $"a1".isNull doesn't seem to work.  Could it be because of how I'm constructing the dataframe I'm using to test, which is as follows?

```
val schema = StructType(
                StructField("a1", StringType, false) ::
                StructField("a2", StringType, false) :: Nil
)

val data = sc.parallelize(Array(
                Row("foo","bar"),
                Row("N/A","baz"),
                Row(null,"etc"))
)

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

I also can't use coalesce, as far as I know, because sometimes I need to use a static value instead of another column's value.

Edit again: Setting my test columns to nullable = false doesn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because null means no value and shouldn't be checked like this.

Use `isNull` function:

```
val df3 = df2.withColumn("a1", when($"a1".isNull, $"a2"))
```

or `coalesce`, which returns first non-null value:

```
val df3 = df2.withColumn("a1", coalesce($"a1", $"a2"))
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried isNull and it didn't seem to work.  I added some detail about how I construct my test dataframe in case that's the problem with that.  I also don't think I can use coalesce because sometimes I need to use a static value rather than the value of another column

Comment: @yoel It because your schema has nullable = false ;) It can't work with null