# Add column to dataframe based on value in other column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe which shows (daily) how many times a product has been used. It looks like this:

```
| x_id | product | usage | yyyy_mm_dd | status |
|------|---------|-------|------------|--------|
| 10   | prod_go | 15    | 2020-10-10 | i      |
| 10   | prod_rv | 7     | 2020-10-10 | fc     |
| 10   | prod_mb | 0     | 2020-10-10 | n      |
| 15   | prod_go | 0     | 2020-10-10 | n      |
| 15   | prod_rv | 5     | 2020-10-10 | fc     |
| 15   | prod_mb | 1     | 2020-10-10 | fc     |
| 10   | prod_go | 20    | 2020-10-11 | i      |
| 10   | prod_rv | 11    | 2020-10-11 | i      |
| 10   | prod_mb | 3     | 2020-10-11 | fc     |
| 15   | prod_go | 0     | 2020-10-11 | n      |
| 15   | prod_rv | 5     | 2020-10-11 | fc     |
| 15   | prod_mb | 1     | 2020-10-11 | fc     |
```

The status column is based on `usage`. When `usage` is 0 then it will have `n`. When `usage` is between 1 and 9 and the `status` will be fc. If `usage` is >= 10 then the `status` will be i.

I would like to introduce two additional columns to this Spark dataframe, `date_reached_fc` and `date_reached_i`. These columns should hold the `min(yyyy_mm_dd)` when an `x_id` reached each status respectively for a `product`.

Based on the sample data, the output would look like this:

```
| x_id | product | usage | yyyy_mm_dd | status | date_reached_fc | date_reached_i |
|------|---------|-------|------------|--------|-----------------|----------------|
| 10   | prod_go | 15    | 2020-10-10 | i      | null            | 2020-10-10     |
| 10   | prod_rv | 7     | 2020-10-10 | fc     | 2020-10-10      | null           |
| 10   | prod_mb | 0     | 2020-10-10 | n      | null            | null           |
| 15   | prod_go | 0     | 2020-10-10 | n      | null            | null           |
| 15   | prod_rv | 5     | 2020-10-10 | fc     | 2020-10-10      | null           |
| 15   | prod_mb | 1     | 2020-10-10 | fc     | 2020-10-10      | null           |
| 10   | prod_go | 20    | 2020-10-11 | i      | null            | 2020-10-10     |
| 10   | prod_rv | 11    | 2020-10-11 | i      | 2020-10-10      | 2020-10-11     |
| 10   | prod_mb | 3     | 2020-10-11 | fc     | 2020-10-11      | null           |
| 15   | prod_go | 0     | 2020-10-11 | n      | null            | null           |
| 15   | prod_rv | 5     | 2020-10-11 | fc     | 2020-10-10      | null           |
| 15   | prod_mb | 1     | 2020-10-11 | fc     | 2020-10-10      | null           |
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala DataFrame, copy value of non null column into a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64313339/scala-dataframe-copy-value-of-non-null-column-into-a-new-column)

Comment: As the possible duplicate suggests you can use combination of `withColumn` and `when` to achieve this.

Comment: It half answers it. It helps show how to add a column but not to find the minimum date per status. I think my question has a bit more nuance to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordering is a bit different from your question, but the results should be correct... Basically just use `min` over a window, and also use `when` to filter only the relevant dates.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'date_reached_fc',
    F.min(F.when(F.col('status') == 'fc', F.col('yyyy_mm_dd'))).over(Window.partitionBy('x_id', 'product').orderBy('yyyy_mm_dd', 'usage'))
).withColumn(
    'date_reached_i',
    F.min(F.when(F.col('status') == 'i', F.col('yyyy_mm_dd'))).over(Window.partitionBy('x_id', 'product').orderBy('yyyy_mm_dd', 'usage'))
).orderBy('x_id', 'product', 'yyyy_mm_dd', 'usage')

df2.show()
+----+-------+-----+----------+------+---------------+--------------+
|x_id|product|usage|yyyy_mm_dd|status|date_reached_fc|date_reached_i|
+----+-------+-----+----------+------+---------------+--------------+
|  10|prod_go|   15|2020-10-10|     i|           null|    2020-10-10|
|  10|prod_go|   20|2020-10-11|     i|           null|    2020-10-10|
|  10|prod_mb|    0|2020-10-10|     n|           null|          null|
|  10|prod_mb|    3|2020-10-11|    fc|     2020-10-11|          null|
|  10|prod_rv|    7|2020-10-10|    fc|     2020-10-10|          null|
|  10|prod_rv|   11|2020-10-11|     i|     2020-10-10|    2020-10-11|
|  15|prod_go|    0|2020-10-10|     n|           null|          null|
|  15|prod_go|    0|2020-10-11|     n|           null|          null|
|  15|prod_mb|    1|2020-10-10|    fc|     2020-10-10|          null|
|  15|prod_mb|    1|2020-10-11|    fc|     2020-10-10|          null|
|  15|prod_rv|    5|2020-10-10|    fc|     2020-10-10|          null|
|  15|prod_rv|    5|2020-10-11|    fc|     2020-10-10|          null|
+----+-------+-----+----------+------+---------------+--------------+
```